# I want to Database Layout for Optgroup Dropdown

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to show some data on page in form of optgroup dropdown, so i just want to database layout like

```
$arr = array(
    'optgroup' => array(
        '1','2','3'),
    'optgroup2' => array(
        '1','2','3')
);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i need a example of database format to happen this in PHP. like country->state combination.

Comment: @ManishPrajapati I understand that English isn't everyone's first language, but it is really difficult to understand what you are asking. However with that said, you still need to provide more code. This isn't a site where you can just ask people to do all your work for you. You need to try something and come back when you have a specific problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given the DB as described by sgt BOSE.

**Countries**

```
id | name
```

**States**

```
id | country_id | name
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `states` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `countries`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `states`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `countries`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `states`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

**And the two models:**

```
<?php // File: Model/Country.php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Country extends AppModel {
  public $hasMany = array('State');
}


<?php // File: Model/State.php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class State extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo  = 'Country';
}
```

In **CountriesController.php**:

```
public function test(){ 
    $countries = $this->Country->find('all');
    $countries = Set::combine($countries, '{n}.Country.name', '{n}.State.{n}.name');
    $this->set('countries', $countries);
}
```

$countries now hold an array as described in the question and is sent to the view

```
array(
    'Norway' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Oslo',
        (int) 1 => 'Bergen'
    ),
    'Sweeden' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Stockholm',
        (int) 1 => 'Göteborg',
        (int) 2 => 'Malmö'
    )
)
```

**In the view** (View/Countries/test.ctp in my case)

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->select('field', $countries);
?>
```

**Will create the following html code:** (This is a drop down)

```
<select name="data[field]" id="field">
  <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="Norway">
    <option value="0">Oslo</option>
    <option value="1">Bergen</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Sweeden">
    <option value="0">Stockholm</option>
    <option value="1">Göteborg</option>
    <option value="2">Malmö</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Changed the SQL to include primary key and auto_increment.

Comment: You really shouldn’t have spent your time provided the OP with copy-and-paste code when they clearly hadn’t tried anything themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The db table structure should be -

**Countries**

```
id | name
```

**States**

```
id | country_id | name
```

The relation should be -

```
Country HasMany State
```

And after fetching all the countries by -

```
$countries = ClassRegistry::init('Country')->find(
   'all', 
   array(
    'conditions' => your conditions,
    'fields'     => array(fields),
    'contain'    => 'State',
   )
)
```

Generate the `optGroup` array as needed by looping through the array.

Comment: Thanks for describing database view.

Comment: You really shouldn’t have spent your time provided the OP with copy-and-paste code when they clearly hadn’t tried anything themselves.

Comment: @MartinBean just gave some hint of how to do this.